# How to calculate calorie burned walking steps?

Tags: calories, walking, calculation

I need the formula to make a step count application.

I need the formula to calculate 1 step of calories without a GPS.

I have variables (sex,age,weight,height,step)

I have found this formula : Step =  height(cm) x 0.4

Can anybody explain this to me?

[image]

Comment: Depends on many factors above these things. Speed of walk, is the surface on an incline? You don't just burn calories per step, hence why step counters aren't as good as GPS monitored devices

Comment: @Twyxz The only thing that GPS has over a step counter is accurate distance measured, no? (Assuming that elevation isn't being measured.) A step counter that takes stride length into account should be relatively accurate enough, as long as there's a caveat that the number will be very generic.

Comment: @LuxClaridge GPS devices 9/10 times can measure speed

Comment: The walking surface no an incline, I have average walking speed by age